# TFS : How to Get the details of Gated- Checked-in files?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

**My requirement :**   is When a developer does a Gated check-in, a copy of all those files which were checked-in should be sent to a known location.(may be different server).After which, I need to do some process, which decides whether that build should fail or pass.

**Things I have tried till now :**

- Created a Team Project.
- Created a new build definition with “Gated Check-in” as Trigger.
- In .xaml file, I have used a “InvokeProcess” tool which calls a .bat file for every check-in.
- .bat file in turn executes a simple script which creates a simple .txt file.(This was done Just to know that InvokeProcess is
  actually working).
- Also tried executing commands through tf.exe (command line tool), to get latest changesets.
- May be if we can get details of files(name & path of the files) which were checked-in by running the command on tf.exe through the .bat file,
  it would be helpful to send those files.

Am I on right direction? If not, please help me out. or If there is any other better options to achieve this, please let me know. 
I am new to TFS, any inputs will help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds weird. What, specifically, is your end-goal here? What do you intend to do with the contents of the changeset?

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the reply. I just want to send a copy of files which were checked-in to some location. So I thought changeset command might help me get the files names which were checked-in, from which I can try to get those files.

Comment: Right, but *why* do you want to copy the contents of the changeset somewhere else? I just don't see the point.

Comment: I want the details of checked-in files like file name, its path, which in turn will help in getting those files.
I thought changeset command will help me get those details.

Comment: There isn't a changeset during a gated checkin. TFS creates a shelveset with the changes while it runs the build. This allows it to make sure the software builds with the changeset in place *without* creating a changeset. That way, there's no need to roll back the changeset if the build fails. I'm not sure off the top of my head if you can see the contents of a shelveset with `tf shelvesets` or not. I still don't understand why you want to get this information, though.

Comment: Oops, I dint knew that changeset will not be created for Gated-check-ins, I'll try **tf shelvesets** and will see if I can get the contents.
I need to achieve simple thing, I just need to get those files which were checked-in, and do some business logic with those files. If it pass, I need it to pass the build else I need to fail the build.

I need your help in guiding me in right direction working.

Comment: It sounds like you might be after a check-in policy -- you can create a plugin that will allow you to programmatically access the list of files that are *about* to be checked in and disallow the checkin if it fails to adhere to your policy.

Comment: @DanielMann thank you for your helpful reply. I'll try to learn more on check-in policies and will work on it.
I just now found interesting solution to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452813/visual-studio-tfs-check-in-migration?rq=1 , Like to add any points on it?..